# Trying to ask if the user want to do another round. In java code

Tags: java

Here is the while loop that I want to start over with a new opponent if  the player is still alive and wish to fight another opponent. At the moment when the player defeats his opponent and the while loop finishes, it goes to the endGame() method and finishes the game instead of waiting for another user input. So basically, how can I get the java terminal to wait for another user input and then start with the battle() method containing a while loop again.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class FieldOfHonor {
    private Player player;
    private ArrayList<Opponent> opponents;
    private Opponent currentOpponent;
    private Random random;
    private InputReader reader;
    private String stance;

    /**
     * Initializes a FieldOfHonor with a player, a list of opponents,
     * a Random-object and a random opponent.
     * 
     * @param player - the player who will shoot 'em up
     * @param opponents - target practice
     */
    public FieldOfHonor(Player player, ArrayList<Opponent> opponents) {
        this.player = player;
        this.opponents = opponents;
        this.random = new Random();
        this.currentOpponent = selectRandomOpponent();
        this.reader = new InputReader();
    }

    /**
     * Starts the battle and handles input from the player. Controls which methods are called
     * during battle.
     */
    public void battle() {
        printWelcome();
        while(this.player.isAlive() && this.currentOpponent.isAlive()) {
            String input = reader.getInput();
            if(input.contains("attack")) {
                newRound();
            } else if (input.contains("run")) {
                run();
                break;
            } else if (input.contains("joke")) {
                System.out.println("What did the homeless man get for christmas? Nothing.");
            } else if (input.contains("use")){
                String itemName = input.replace("use ", "");
                player.useItem(itemName);
            } else if (input.contains("stance "+"")){
                this.player.setStance(input.split(" ", 2) [1]);
            }
            else {
                System.err.println("What? Choose 'attack', 'joke' 'use <item>' or 'run'");
            } 
        }

        endGame();
    }

    /**
     * Handles one round of attacking. The player attacks the opponent and the opponent
     * attacks back if it is still alive after the player attack
     */
    public void newRound() {
        int dmgToOpponent = this.player.attack(this.currentOpponent);
        System.out.println(this.player.getName() + " attacks " + this.currentOpponent.getName());
        System.out.println(this.currentOpponent.getName() + " looses " + dmgToOpponent + " hp");
        System.out.println(this.currentOpponent.getName() + " now has " + this.currentOpponent.getHealth() + " hp");
        System.out.println();
        if(this.currentOpponent.isAlive()) {
            int dmgToPlayer = this.currentOpponent.attack(this.player);
            System.out.println(this.currentOpponent.getName() + " attacks " + this.player.getName());
            System.out.println(this.player.getName() + " looses " + dmgToPlayer + " hp");
            System.out.println(this.player.getName() + " now has " + this.player.getHealth() + " hp");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles what happens if the player runs away. Takes 25 reputation from the player.
     */
    public void run() {
        int reputationLoss = 25;
        this.player.setReputation(this.player.getReputation() - reputationLoss);
        System.out.println(this.player.getName() + " runs from the duel and looses " + reputationLoss + " reputation.");
    }

     public void endGame() {
         String input = reader.getInput();   
         int pointsWon = this.random.nextInt(91) + 10;
            this.player.setReputation(this.player.getReputation() + pointsWon);
            System.out.println(this.player.getName() + " wins the game and an extra " + pointsWon + " reputation");
            System.out.println("");
        if(this.player.isAlive() && !this.currentOpponent.isAlive() && opponents.size() != 0 ) {
            System.out.println("Do you want to fight another opponent? yes or run?");
            if(input.contains("yes")){
            this.selectRandomOpponent();
            this.battle();
          }
        } else if(!this.currentOpponent.isAlive()){
            System.out.println("You died and left the game");
        }
        System.out.println("Game Over.");

    }

    /**
     * Prints a welcome message at the start of the battle
     */
    public void printWelcome() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Field of Honor!");
        System.out.println("Your opponent is " + this.currentOpponent.getName() + "!");
    }

    /**
     * Selects a random opponent from the list of opponents
     * and removes it from the list.
     * 
     * @return a random opponent
     */
    public Opponent selectRandomOpponent() {
        return this.opponents.remove(this.random.nextInt(this.opponents.size()));
    }
}
```

// main method for launching the game

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Weapon weapon1 = new Weapon("Bare hands", "Skullcrusher and facebreaker", 0, 0, "punch", 1000);
        Weapon weapon2 = new Weapon("Winchester Carbine", "Fires .44-40 cartridge shots", 40, 8, "shoots", 30);
        Weapon weapon3 = new Weapon("Knife", "A small but sharp blade", 10, 1, "cuts", 10);
        Weapon weapon4 = new Weapon("Colt .45", "A fine six-shot revolver", 50, 3, "shoots", 20);
        Potion potion1 = new Potion("Fullrestore", "A magical elixir that heals some health", 15, 4, "Heals some health", 100);
        Potion potion2 = new Potion("Apple", "Tasty tree fruit. One of five each day", 10, 1, "eats", 20);
        Potion potion3 = new Potion("Health Potion", "A red liquid that heals wounds when you drink it.. weird, I know", 10, 1, "drinks", 50);

        Player player1 = new Player("Billy", "Thief", 50, 20, 50, weapon1);

        player1.addItem(weapon1);
        player1.addItem(weapon2);
        player1.addItem(weapon3);
        player1.addItem(weapon4);
        player1.addItem(potion1);
        player1.addItem(potion2);
        player1.addItem(potion3);

        System.out.println(player1);

        ArrayList<Opponent> opponents = new ArrayList<Opponent>();
        opponents.add(new Opponent("Billy the Kid", "Gang Leader", 30));
        opponents.add(new Opponent("Joe Dalton", "Robber", 35));
        opponents.add(new Opponent("Everett Murdoch", "Nemesis", 50));
        opponents.add(new Opponent("Marty McFly", "FutureMan", 22));
        opponents.add(new Opponent("Rattata", "Dog", 21));

        FieldOfHonor fieldOfHonor = new FieldOfHonor(player1, opponents);
        fieldOfHonor.battle();
    }
}
```

Comment: paste the console output that you see?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/nZZZbyK.png

Comment: I dont see screen shot there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the reason why it is so difficult to ask after `game over` whether you want to restart or not is due to the fact that you possibly without realizing it are using `recursion` to restart the game.

You call

```
   fieldOfHonor.battle();
```

Then you go to

```
    endGame();
```

Which goes to

```
     if(this.player.isAlive() && !this.currentOpponent.isAlive() && opponents.size() != 0 ) {
        System.out.println("Do you want to fight another opponent? yes or run?");
        if(input.contains("yes")){
        this.selectRandomOpponent();
        this.battle(); // <-- look at that line of recursion right there
     }
```

Which "restarts" the game. In reality, you could just replace this with a boolean return value and a do-while loop.

```
public void battle() {
    boolean restart = false;
    do {
        printWelcome();
        while (this.player.isAlive() && this.currentOpponent.isAlive()) {
            String input = reader.getInput();
            if (input.contains("attack")) {
                newRound();
            } else if (input.contains("run")) {
                run();
                break;
            } else if (input.contains("joke")) {
                System.out.println("What did the homeless man get for christmas? Nothing.");
            } else if (input.contains("use")) {
                String itemName = input.replace("use ", "");
                player.useItem(itemName);
            } else if (input.contains("stance " + "")) {
                this.player.setStance(input.split(" ", 2)[1]);
            } else {
                System.err.println("What? Choose 'attack', 'joke' 'use <item>' or 'run'");
            }
        }
        restart = endGame();
    } while (restart);
}
```

Like so

```
 public boolean endGame() {
     boolean restart = false;
     String input = reader.getInput();   
     int pointsWon = this.random.nextInt(91) + 10;
        this.player.setReputation(this.player.getReputation() + pointsWon);
        System.out.println(this.player.getName() + " wins the game and an extra " + pointsWon + " reputation");
        System.out.println("");
    if(this.player.isAlive() && !this.currentOpponent.isAlive() && opponents.size() != 0 ) {
        System.out.println("Do you want to fight another opponent? yes or run?");
        if(input.contains("yes")){
        this.selectRandomOpponent();
        //this.battle(); // nope
        restart = true;
      }
    } else if(!this.currentOpponent.isAlive()){
        System.out.println("You died and left the game");
    }

    if(!restart) { // changed here slightly
        System.out.println("Game Over.");
    }
    return restart;
}
```

This way, you can just change

```
    FieldOfHonor fieldOfHonor = new FieldOfHonor(player1, opponents);
    String input = "no";
    do {
        fieldOfHonor.battle();
        System.out.println("Would you like to play another game?");
        input = reader.readInput();
    } while("yes".equals(input));
```

Comment: That worked, and now I even learned that I could add a boolean if I want to restart or not from another method! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! :) If it worked from beginning to end, please consider ticking that checkmark thing at the topleft of the answer to "accept" it.

Comment: Okey :) This was my first post here, so I didn't know about that, hehe. Thanks for your help, It really helped :)